# Early image binding issue for treeviewer

Tags: java, view, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have treeviewer in project explorer that is at perspective level. I want to have children item icons under treeviewer changes as per the condition. May i change item icon as per created, currently I resolved image path at imageRegistry level and i got the condition when tree item is to be created.

May i have any listener or property change handler to change icon whenever i needed.

like this:

```
  public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener 
      listener) {
    // changing 
  }
```

Comment: Do you have your own content & label providers for the items, or are you wanting to change existing items? Do you want to replace the whole icon, or just decorate it?

Comment: @NickWilson  Thanks for the reply, I have my content and label provider but they take setImage from ImageRegistry and for all node it become one That is too early, I put some condition for setImage but it is generalize.

Answer (score 0):

In the property change listener you should identify the element(s) that need to have their icons updated and call the `TreeViewer.update()` method for those elements. Don't make the decision at that point what image to display.

Inside the `LabelProvider.getImage()` method is where you should check your element and conditions then retrieve the correct image from the `ImageRegistry`.